# In Powerpoint 2011, once I've "Rehearsed" a presentation, how do I view the analysis?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I'm using the "Rehearse" feature in Powerpoint 2011 (Mac), and I've saved the finished rehearsal timings (i.e. it prompted me after finishing the presentation). How do I view the amount of time I used on each slide?

Answer (score 1):

I completely misunderstood this feature.  Saving the timings is not simply a debugging tool, it actually sets the "advance to next slide" time. To view (and remove), go to each indvidual slide, and under Transitions, this shows in the "Advance Slide" option for "After _____".